# Using regular expressions to modify a string in R

Tags: r, regex

I have trimmed down an html file to get each character vector of a data set to look like:

```
<h3 class=\"personName\">Whitney  Alicia Zimmerman</h3>                                             <li>Assistant Teaching Professor</li>"
```

I want to use regular expressions to trim it down to just the name and position (for clarification, each vector has different names and positions). What I used before won't work for this (I used the grepl function to subset my original html file). How would I go about trimming this using regular expressions or even another technique? Thanks for any help in advance.

Or if it's easier to work with, I have two other character vectors separating the two that look like:

```
"                                        <h3 class=\"personName\">Whitney  Alicia Zimmerman</h3>"
```

and

```
"                                            <li>Assistant Teaching Professor</li>"
```

Comment: Dupe of [Parsing HTML file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748130/parsing-html-file-in-r)? 
 Or [R Read & Parse HTML to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907455/r-read-parse-html-to-list). There are better ways than using regex when parsing HTML.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's probably more practical. Unfortunately, I'm trying to learn regex better for a class I'm in, and I"m trying to avoid cutting corners with ways like that. Thanks for the advice though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sub` and match everything but what you want. So I'd probably do something like

```
test = '<h3 class=\\"personName\\">Whitney  Alicia Zimmerman</h3>  '
sub("<.*", "", sub(".*\">", "", test))

[1] "Whitney  Alicia Zimmerman"
```

That `gsub` expression can be modified to get rid of whatever you want. The trick is to match the stuff you don't want, and substitute in the empty string.

The basic structure to `sub` is `sub(match_string, replace_string, target)`. Looking at the documentation will clear it up further. I've just nested my `sub`s so I can remove the start and end of the string.

**EDIT:** I included u/Onyambu's suggestion, as he is completely right. Only `sub` is required not `gsub` like I originally suggested. The difference is `gsub` looks for all matches, `sub` just looks for the first.

Below he also provides a solution using just one `sub` rather than two like I have.

Comment: gsub seems like a relatively simple way to get rid of all of the junk around it. I'll try to work with that more and see what I can do with it with other stuff. Thank you

Comment: What you need is `sub(".*>(.*)<.*","\\1",test)` . You do not need to use the `g` sub ie `gsub` but it will still give the same results:  `gsub(".*>(.*)<.*","\\1",test)`

Comment: Good one! I have a bad habit of using `gsub` all the time because most my matches are singular. I'm not a regex expert, can you explain to me how the `\\1` works? Does it match the whole string, then sub in its place the 1st (as in 0th, 1st, 2nd) matched token, or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to use regex, here's a solution that uses `stringr` (as well as `magrittr`):

Using your long string:

```
htmlstring <- c("<h3 class=\"personName\">Whitney  Alicia Zimmerman</h3>                                             <li>Assistant Teaching Professor</li>")
```

The code:

```
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

ParsedString <- str_replace_all(htmlstring, "<[^>]+>", "") %>% # remove everything between angle brackets, inclusive
                str_squish # remove all extraneous whitespace
```

Output:

```
> ParsedString
[1] "Whitney Alicia Zimmerman Assistant Teaching Professor"
```

Comment: I don't reallllly want to use to regex, but I do need some foundation in the field. But this helps in understanding how to use them

Comment: Glad to help! For a `gsub` solution, try `ParsedString <- gsub("<[^>]+>", "", htmlstring) %>%
                gsub("\\s{2,}", " ", .)`